# UIViewcontroller not reloading after notification from observer

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, afnetworking, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

Hi I have a uiviewcontroller that adds 4 childviews after receiving data from a webservice.  I add an observer to the uiviewcontroller that watches when the data is completely loaded from the webservice.  Once it is, the uiviewcontroler adds 4 childviews.

however my problem is it doesn't do this unless i switch to another tab view than go back to that tab again.

Is there a way to reload this page?  I used   [uiviewcontroller.view setNeedsDisplay] under the function that responds to the notification from the observer but the view doesn't refresh.

thanks for your guys' help :)

here is my observer function:

```
 -(void)projectListFromServer:(NSNotification *) response

{
NSLog(@"%@",response);


for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    childview2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(@"slider")];
    childview2.image = @"wicked";
    childview2.couponID = @"cool";

    NSLog(@"%@", self.childview2.couponID);
    [self addChildViewController:childview2];
}

 [self.childview.view setNeedsDisplay];


}
```

Comment: You won't need to call `setNeedsDisplay` after adding subviews. Someone can help you with the actual bug if you post code to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `addChildViewController`, but then it looks like you aren't actually adding `childview2`'s view hierarchy to this containing view controller's view hierarchy.

You'll need to do something like this, adjusted of course depending on where in your current hierarchy you actually want these new views to be inserted:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.childview2]; // assuming childview2 is a @property
[self.view addSubview:self.childview2.view]; // adjust based on your actual hierarchy
[self.childview2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

BTW, you should avoid giving view controllers names like `childview2`. Views and view controllers are two completely different things.

Comment: You are right I added the subview and the view popped up.  However, I'm creating a slider view where you can sideswipe and see all the child views.  By using self.view addsubview I just add one childview ot the heirachy when i need multiple childviews.  How do I fix this?  Thanks for your help Lafeer!!

Comment: I figured out the solution. You add a uiviewcontroller before the parent controller and load the data there. Once you push to the ne next controller which is the parent for the slider view all the childviews are already added to the heirachy. Pretty simple solution feel stupid for not figuring that out earlier :P